# Full-width body background to match responsive column layout

Tags: css, responsive-design

I may well be asking for the moon on a stick, here, but: I'm trying to figure out how to get a two-colour background to delineate the two columns of the main content.

The background must be full viewport width (edge-to-edge), and the central content is responsive with a `max-width` of 960px, split into two columns; the first column is 2/3 of the width (max of 640px wide) and the second column takes up the remaining 1/3 (max of 320px wide). Probably the easiest way to explain it is with a GIF:

[image: Responsive!]

As you can see, the left-hand part of the light blue 'sidebar' background colour always lines up with the left side of the actual sidebar column. It was pointed out to me that the [checkout on woothemes.com](https://www.woothemes.com/checkout/) has pretty much this exact same effect (although I think you need to add something to your basket to see it). They appear to have achieved it with `linear-gradient`, and it boils down to this:

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg,#fff 53.5%,#f0f4f5 46.5%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,#fff 52%,#f0f4f5 46.5%);
```

The problems are:

1. I don't understand these declarations at all - why are the second color-stop's values lower than the first (and why is the `-moz` declaration's first color-stop a different percentage)? Adjusting it doesn't seem to make a difference, but I definitely need to update the values, as they don't match what I need... but I *don't get it.*
2. Although the effect is *close*, it unfortunately is not perfect: for a start, the stop between the two colours is kinda blurry; and worse, the line does 'drift' when rescaling. Although it's only by a small amount, unfortunately it's enough to kill the illusion with the design I've been given.

I've tried a couple of methods, including variations of `linear-gradient` and a pseudo-element with percentage & `calc()`-based offsets, but I'm totally not getting it. I've debated whether this is something I can achieve with some super-clever SVG element handling, but I seem to be totally stuck on something that looks deceptively simple.

Is there a way to achieve this with pure CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look into the woothemes.com example, but here's my take:

http://jsbin.com/jofeseseyo/edit?css,output

This would need to be adapted a bit based on the rest of the site, but the idea is: one container of max 960px, with two children (66.666% and 33.333% width). Each child has a pseudo-element that is absolutely positioned at the point where the two columns meet. Then they are z-indexed behind everything.

I don't know how the rest of your site looks, so I left the rest a bit arbitrary. The background color columns have a fixed height, right now at 200vh.

Comment: Gah - that _almost_ nails it! Unfortunately I can't get it to work without an arbitrary height on the pseudo-element. If I can get the sidebar column to stretch to the height of its parent, then I might be able to get to work with `bottom: 0` on the pseudo-element.

Comment: Well, if you're not afraid of a little javascript: http://jsbin.com/legutulufi/edit?js,output  I'm sure you could do it without jQuery too, I just used it for convenience's sake.

Comment: Nailed it - I was using flexbox anyway, so I just added `align-items: stretch;` to the parent wrapper for 100% height, and then removed the `height` from the pseudo-element and added `bottom: 0;` - works like a charm!